# How to convert Number to Date Using date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I m trying to convert number into Date using date-fns.

Current : 20220211 or '20220211' (May be number or string)

Expected : Fri 11Feb

Comment: why don't you read the integer ad a string and create a date based on what you read? `const date = new Date(dateString.substring(0, 4), dateString.substring(4, 6), dateString.substring(6, 8));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date-fns takes `Date` as an argument. First you should convert your string date value to a valid `Date` instance. `Date` could take several types of value, including  ISO 8601 date standard, which means you could pass `2022-02-22` string value to `Date` constructor and it will be valid.

If your string format is not going to change your could do this:

```
const dateStr = '20220211';
const year = dateStr.slice(0,4);
const month = dateStr.slice(4,6);
const day = dateStr.slice(6,8);
const date = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
```

And then use `date` in `date-fns`